# Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

Tags: android

I want to create new project android app in Android Studio 3.2.1. I made it by File>New...>New Project

but it shows error Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) when I tried run app to my device

A few methods I tried but no success :

1. Close Android Studio. Delete C:\Users\LENOVO-ANDROID.gradle\wrapper\dists\xxgradle file and Start Android Studio
2. Change to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
3. Use same Gradle and Android Plug Version as other Project Structure's app

Previously my PC shutdown for few times due to electric trip.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I uninstall Android Studio, 
Shutdown PC,
Start PC,
Install Android Studio.

Comment: OK. But I can only accept it on tomorrow , I will accept it on tomorrow